# How can I multiply columns whose name begins with a certain string by another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, syntax, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply certain columns within a data frame by one specific column. While the specific column will always be the same, the names and number of the other columns will vary so I cannot specify those column names except for what the string they begin with. I have been trying to use .mul but have had trouble getting it to work. Any way I can do this?

Original DF

| ID # | Column To Multiply By | ABC Column1 | ABC Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 13 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 14 | 4 | 1 | 2 |

Desired DF

| ID # | Column To Multiply By | ABC Column1 | ABC Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 13 | 3 | 3 | 6 |
| 14 | 4 | 4 | 8 |

I tried using the line below but am met with a syntax error:

df2 = df1.loc[:, df1.columns.str.startswith('ABC').mul(df1.Column to Multiply By, axis=0)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the  work:

```
df2 = df1
df2['ABC Column1'] = df1['Column To Multiply By'] * df1['ABC Column1']  
df2['ABC Column2'] = df1['Column To Multiply By'] * df1['ABC Column2']
```

Edit: If the name of ABC columns changes but the prefix is constant, this should work:

```
df[df.columns[pd.Series(df.columns).str.startswith('ABC')]] = df[df.columns[pd.Series(df.columns).str.startswith('ABC')]].multiply(df['Column To Multiply By'], axis='index')
```

Comment: Hi, as the names of the ABC columns are subject to change, this would not work. I will only know the beginning string of the ABC column titles.

Comment: @RichardMunch Sorry, I edited my answer to hopefully fulfill your requirements now.